# Python 3.10 error en virtualenv: "Unable to create process using [PATH hacia python.exe]"

Tags: python, virtualenv

Mi problema es que luego de activar mi virtualenv si pongo en la linea de comandos cualquier comando de python como "py", "python", "pip", "pip3"; me salta el error del titulo:

*Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe*

Está todo actualizado, y tanto el pip como python 3.10 estan en el PATH del sistema (como unicas versiones). Ya probe desinstalando y reeinstalando todo pero no cambia nada. Y cuando utilizo estos comandos fuera del virtualenv me los reconoce sin problemas.
Alguna idea de que puedo probar?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo activas el entorno virtual después de haberlo creado?

Comment: Desde la linea de comandos en el directorio del entorno: .\env\Scripts\activate (env es el nombre que le puse)

Comment: y usas powershell o cmd?

Comment: Probe con ambos y no funciona